# Inequalities of orbital angular momentum eigenvalues (show that is bounded)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

If we apply the rising/lowering operators for angular momentum to a state $|{l,m}\rangle$, we get:

\begin{align}
 L_+|{l,m}\rangle = C_+(l,m)|{l,m+1}\rangle \\
 L_-|{l,m}\rangle = C_-(l,m)|{l,m-1}\rangle
\end{align}

it can be shown that:
\begin{align}
 C_+(l,m) = \hbar\sqrt{(l-m)(l+m+1)}\\
 C_-(l,m) = \hbar\sqrt{(l+m)(l-m+1)}
\end{align}

thus:

\begin{align}
 L_+|{l,m}\rangle = \hbar\sqrt{(l-m)(l+m+1)}|{l,m+1}\rangle \\
 L_-|{l,m}\rangle = \hbar\sqrt{(l+m)(l-m+1)}|{l,m-1}\rangle
\end{align}

On the other hand:

\begin{align}
 \langle{L_\pm(l,m)|L_\pm(l,m)}\rangle \geq 0
\end{align}

And it follows from (7) that:

\begin{align}
 \langle{L_\pm(l,m)|L_\pm(l,m)}\rangle &= \langle{l,m|L_\mp L_\pm|l,m}\rangle\\
 & = \langle{l,m|L^{2} - L_{z}^{2} \pm\hbar L_z|l,m}\rangle\\
 & = \hbar^2 [l(l+1) - m(m\mp 1)] \geq 0
\end{align}

This implies that both:

\begin{align}
 l(l+1) - m(m- 1) \geq 0\\
 l(l+1)- m(m+ 1) \geq 0  
\end{align}

Now here comes my doubt, gasiorowicz's book (Quantum Physics, Thrid Edition, Chapter 7) claims: Since $l\geq 0$ It follows form the above that:

\begin{align}
 -l\leq m \leq l
\end{align}

But i cant see how the above inequalities imples the last one. Any help would be appriciate, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0\leq l<m$, then $l+1<m+1$, so multiplying these inequalities yields
\begin{align}
l(l+1)<m(m+1)
\end{align}
(we can do this since everything is non-negative), so this violates the second inequality you wrote down.

Next, suppose $m<-l$, which means $0\leq l<-m$, and thus by the same reasoning as above, we have
\begin{align}
l(l+1)&< (-m)[(-m)+1]\\
&=m(m-1)
\end{align}

which violates your first inequality.

Therefore, we must have $-l\leq m\leq l$.

Comment: Thank you!, this was very helpful, now i understand where the last inequality came from.